# how to arrange two images side by side in list view in windows phone RT app

Tags: image, listview, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing windows phone app,in this app I want to arrange two images side by side using list view control. Actually what happend is I am binding images in listview ,but images are binding one image below another image was binding . how to arrange images side by side in listview and how to set  width of the image in all the resolution screens.please help me.

Below is my sample code.

```
<ListView x:Name="listviewfreecredits" Margin="0,-1,0.643,10" Height="521" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="listviewfreecredits_ItemClick">

                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel >
                                    <Grid Margin="10,10,50,10" Width="389" >


                                        <Image Source="{Binding DealImage}" Stretch="None" Width="400" Height="300" />


                                    </Grid>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>


  string result = "";

                HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(Url.weburl + "FreeCredits_v2?PlatFormID=7") as HttpWebRequest;
                request.Method = "GET";


                WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    // Do anything with you content. Convert it to xml, json or anything.
                }


                JObject jobj = JObject.Parse(result);
                JArray jarr = (JArray)jobj["Deals"];
                if (jarr != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < jarr.Count; i++)
                    {
                        string DealImage = (string)jarr[i]["DealImage"];
                        string DealID = (string)jarr[i]["DealID"];
                        string Buttontext = (string)jarr[i]["Buttontext"];

                        freecredit obj = new freecredit();
                        obj.DealImage = Url.imgurl + DealImage;
                        obj.DealID = DealID;
                        obj.ButtonText = Buttontext;
                        this.listviewfreecredits.Items.Add(obj);

                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use GridView control instead of ListView, and for width for each image you can calculate it and bind width and height and height of the image in your image control. e.g.

```
<GridView x:Name="listviewfreecredits" Margin="0,-1,0.643,10" Height="521" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="listviewfreecredits_ItemClick">

                    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel >
                                <Grid Margin="10,10,50,10" Width="389" >


                                    <Image Source="{Binding DealImage}" Stretch="None" Width="{Bind ImageWidth}" Height="{Bind ImageWidth}" />


                                </Grid>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                </GridView>

for (int i = 0; i < jarr.Count; i++)
                {
                    string DealImage = (string)jarr[i]["DealImage"];
                    string DealID = (string)jarr[i]["DealID"];
                    string Buttontext = (string)jarr[i]["Buttontext"];

                    freecredit obj = new freecredit();
                    obj.DealImage = Url.imgurl + DealImage;
                    obj.DealID = DealID;
                    obj.ButtonText = Buttontext;
                    //set image width, height by calculating with height accordingly
                    obj.ImageWidth = ((Windows.UI.Xaml.Window.Current.Bounds.Width - 50/ 2);
                    this.listviewfreecredits.Items.Add(obj);

                }
```

Define ImageWidth property as double in your freecredit class

Comment: I can't understand what your are said.please explain in detail.